# Are torsion points in a semi-abelian variety over $\mathbb C_p$ bounded?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be a semi-abelian variety defined over (a subfield of) $\mathbb C_p$. Consider its $p$-adic topology with some (non-canonical) metric. Can we bound the distance of torsion points to $0$ with respect to this metric ? In other words (to state this topologically), can we find a sequence of torsion points which leaves any $p$-adically open proper subset of $A$ ? This is true in abelian varieties and tori, because one may take an explicit integral model, but appear to be more complex for non-trivial extensions.

This is somehow related to the Tate-Voloch conjecture, since it states that torsion points cannot be too close to the subvariety at infinity in some compactification of $A$.